# Changepoint detection: How to find several changepoints in a signal sampled from two hypothetical Gaussian distributions with different means?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, signal-processing, time-series

A signal $z$---which is a $1\times m$ dimensional vector---is generated from two hypothetical Normal distributions; $p_1=N(\mu_1,\sigma)$, or $p_2=N(\mu_2,\sigma)$. That is, the difference is only in the mean value. Here, $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, and $\sigma$ are all given. Is there an algorithm to detect at what points the distribution that produces the elements of the signal $z$ changes between the two hypothesis? In our problem, we have more than a single chaingepoint, that is the distribution is probably changing $k\in \{1,2,3,\dots \}$ times. Generally we don't know $k$, but if it helps, we can assume to know a not necessarily exact estimate of it, say $k_{est}$.

I am aware of an algorithm in Matlab that does the job to some extent
findchangepts(z,'Statistic','mean',MaxNumChanges=k_est).

However, this algorithm does not use the fact that we know the mean values and the variance of the two distributions i.e., $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, and $\sigma$. Thus, it is less precise than it could be.

Is anyone aware of this problem being studied in the literature? If yes, is there already a numerical package developed for this algorithm?

Comment: Do you have an a priori estimate of how many changes there'll be in your datasets?

Comment: Yes a priori we estimate that there are $k_{est} $ changes.

Comment: Is the signal assumed to be in one state for a while, then changing to another for some period of time, etc., or is it typically in one state and for a single instant changing to another then falling back to the original?

Comment: Yes, it spends some finite time in either of the states before switching to the other. However, on average it spends more time on one of the two states than the other. A priori, we don't know this average times that the system spends on either state.